# MySQL view query takes very long to load

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created a view in MySQL

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `inventory_view` AS 
select (case when isnull(`a`.`items_sold`) then 0 else `a`.`items_sold` end) AS `sold_qty`,
       (case when isnull(`a`.`items_bought`) then 0 else `a`.`items_bought` end) AS `bought_qty`,
       (case when isnull(`a`.`credit`) then 0 else `a`.`credit` end) AS `credit_amount`,
       (case when isnull(`a`.`debit`) then 0 else `a`.`debit` end) AS `debit_amount`,
       (case when isnull(`tv`.`count`) then 0 else `tv`.`count` end) AS `tranfers`,
       (case when isnull(`a`.`inhand`) then 0 else `a`.`inhand` end) AS `balance`,
       (case when isnull(`tv`.`count`) then `a`.`inhand` when isnull(`a`.`inhand`) then `tv`.`count` else (`a`.`inhand` + `tv`.`count`) end) AS `in_hand`,
       (case when isnull(`a`.`company_id`) then `tv`.`fk_company` else `a`.`company_id` end) AS `company`,
       (case when isnull(`a`.`branch_id`) then `tv`.`fk_branch` else `a`.`branch_id` end) AS `branch`,
       (case when isnull(`a`.`item_code`) then convert(`tv`.`fk_item_code` using utf8) else convert(`a`.`item_code` using utf8) end) AS `item`,
       (case when isnull(`a`.`operator`) then `tv`.`user` else `a`.`operator` end) AS `fk_operator` 
from (`transfer_view` `tv` left join `inventory_main` `a` on(((convert(`tv`.`fk_item_code` using utf8) = convert(`a`.`item_code` using utf8)) and (`a`.`operator` = `tv`.`user`))))
union 
select (case when isnull(`a`.`items_sold`) then 0 else `a`.`items_sold` end) AS `sold_qty`,
       (case when isnull(`a`.`items_bought`) then 0 else `a`.`items_bought` end) AS `bought_qty`,
       (case when isnull(`a`.`credit`) then 0 else `a`.`credit` end) AS `credit_amount`,
       (case when isnull(`a`.`debit`) then 0 else `a`.`debit` end) AS `debit_amount`,
       (case when isnull(`tv`.`count`) then 0 else `tv`.`count` end) AS `tranfers`,
       (case when isnull(`a`.`inhand`) then 0 else `a`.`inhand` end) AS `balance`,
       (case when isnull(`tv`.`count`) then `a`.`inhand` when isnull(`a`.`inhand`) then `tv`.`count` else (`a`.`inhand` + `tv`.`count`) end) AS `in_hand`,
       (case when isnull(`a`.`company_id`) then `tv`.`fk_company` else `a`.`company_id` end) AS `company`,
       (case when isnull(`a`.`branch_id`) then `tv`.`fk_branch` else `a`.`branch_id` end) AS `branch`,
       (case when isnull(`a`.`item_code`) then convert(`tv`.`fk_item_code` using utf8) else convert(`a`.`item_code` using utf8) end) AS `item`,
       (case when isnull(`a`.`operator`) then `tv`.`user` else `a`.`operator` end) AS `fk_operator` 
from (`inventory_main` `a` left join `transfer_view` `tv` on(((convert(`tv`.`fk_item_code` using utf8) = convert(`a`.`item_code` using utf8)) and (`a`.`operator` = `tv`.`user`))));
```

It has thousands of records and performs very slow. Any query I run takes about 50 seconds.

Can you please help me find the mistake or recommend a better way to create the view?

Comment: Don't post the whole thing on one line like that. Add line breaks and indent it so we can see what it's doing.

Comment: The query alone does not tell us anything. Pls include the explain results for the select and a list of all indexes and indexed columns in the affected tables. You also need to tell us what you would like to get out of the report (sample data and expected output based on the sample data would be a big help).

Comment: What does the view do? what is the purpose of this query? You need to specify what it is that you need help with, in a way so that people can understand you, without having your perspective. We're not omniscient in your life.

Answer (score 1):

Create an composite index on transfer_view's fk_item_code and user.

Create an composite index on inventory_main's item_code and operator.

Try switching some of your statements to using `coalesce` like this:

```
create view inventory_view as

select 
       coalesce(a.items_sold, 0) as sold_qty,
       coalesce(a.items_bought, 0) as bought_qty,
       coalesce(a.credit, 0) as credit_amount,
       coalesce(a.debit, 0) as debit_amount,
       coalesce(tv.count, 0) as transfers,
       coalesce(a.inhand, 0) as balance,
       coalesce(tv.count, 0) + coalesce(a.inhand, 0) as in_hand,
       coalesce(a.company_id, tv.fk_company) as company,
       coalesce(a.branch_id, tv.fk_branch) as branch,
       convert(coalesce(a.item_code, tv.fk_item_code) using utf8) as item,
       coalesce(a.operator, tv.user) as fk_operator
from transfer_view tv
left join inventory_main a
       on convert(tv.fk_item_code using utf8) = convert(a.item_code using utf8) 
       and a.operator = tv.user

union 

select 
       coalesce(a.items_sold, 0) as sold_qty,
       coalesce(a.items_bought, 0) as bought_qty,
       coalesce(a.credit, 0) as credit_amount,
       coalesce(a.debit, 0) as debit_amount,
       coalesce(tv.count, 0) as transfers,
       coalesce(a.inhand, 0) as balance,
       coalesce(tv.count, 0) + coalesce(a.inhand, 0) as in_hand,
       coalesce(a.company_id, tv.fk_company) as company,
       coalesce(a.branch_id, tv.fk_branch) as branch,
       convert(coalesce(a.item_code, tv.fk_item_code) using utf8) as item,
       coalesce(a.operator, tv.user) as fk_operator
from inventory_main a
left join transfer_view tv 
       on convert(tv.fk_item_code using utf8) = convert(a.item_code using utf8)
       and a.operator = tv.user;
```

Does that improve the performance of your query?

If not, here are the steps I recommend:

- find matching records between both tables
- find all records from transfer_view with no matching records in inventory_main
- find all records from inventory_main with no matching records in transfer_view
- `union all` the three datasets

Example -

```
create view inventory_view as

select 
    ...
from transfer_view tv
inner join inventory_main a
    on tv.fk_item_code = a.item_code -- you can convert ONLY if you need
    and a.operator = tv.user

union all

select
    ...
from transfer_view tv
where not exists (
    select 1 from inventory_main
    where item_code = tv.fk_item_code and operator = tv.user
)

union all

select
    ...
from inventory_main a
where not exists (
    select 1 from transfer_view
    where fk_item_code = a.item_code and user = a.operator
);
```